# Orchard Collaboration tables joins

Tags: orchardcms

I'm new to Orchard CMS and collaboration,I want to know How Orchard Collaboration tables are mapping with each other(i.e joins) like how customer & Project module is linked each other.

Answer (score 0):

The data model of the Orchard is based on ContentItems and ContentParts. Each ContentItem contains several ContentParts. Each ContentPart ( in case it derived from ContentPart not from ContentPart), has its own table in database. ContentParts of a ContentItem have the same primary key value.

Now backing to your question:
Customer is a User with special privilege. Its ContentType is User.
Project is also a ContentItem. Its ContentType is ProjectItem.

Project Type contains a ContentPart called ContentItemPermissionPart. ContentItemPermissionPart specifies which Users and Business-Units have which AccessType to the ContentItem. The associated database tables related to this are ContentItemPermissionPartRecord (master) and ContentItemPermissionDetailRecord (detail).

You can find more information about Orchard data model [Here](http://docs.orchardproject.net/en/latest/Documentation/Understanding-data-access/).

You can find more information about Orchard Collaboration data model [here](http://orchardcollaboration.com/data-model-of-orchardcollaboration).